# Could use some help in probability question

Tags: probability, computational-mathematics

Two distinct numbers are selected simultaneously and at random from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. What is the probability that the smaller one divides the larger one? Express your answer as a common fraction.

Comment: Are these 2 questions related? If not please post 2 seperate questions

Comment: My bad thanks man

Comment: You are more likely to get responses if you share or thoughts and attempts on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ choices of this pair. The ones that qualify are the four of the form $(1,\,n)$ and $(2,\,4)$, and the answer is $\frac12$.